# How to determine the value of the argument entered in the terminal using C language

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I would like to write a program that performs different function based on the argument provided.

For example:

```
$ ./program -a //line 1
$ ./program -b //line 2
```

if I enter line 1 in terminal, I want it to print "Hi"
if I enter line 2 in terminal, I want it to print "Bye"

Here is my current logic, which does not work in C:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] == "-a"){
        printf("Hi");
    } else if (argv[1] == "-b")
    {
        printf("Bye");
    }
```

Can anyone help me fix my code in order to achieve my objective?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't compare a string with `==`, strings are character arrays. You can use something like `strcmp`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know your CL arguments will always be in the format {-x|x of alphabet} you can write:
if(argv[1][0] == '-') { if(argv[1][1] == 'p')...}
However, this could get problematic as you add more arguments or allow multicharacter args, so the elegant solution would be the one Thomas suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare strings in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for strcmp() */

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-a") == 0){
        printf("Hi");
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0)
    {
        printf("Bye");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!! it works. will accept it as an answer when stack overflow allows It :D

Comment: Hmm, in this particular case where the strings come from the arguments or literals, it might make no difference. But in general `strncmp()`, if available, might be the safer choice for comparing strings?